# how to disable windows 10 antimalware service while starting up eclipse

Tags: windows-10, antimalware

Windows 10 version 1809 (OS Build 17763.379)

Whenever I startup eclipse on windows 10, the antimalware service executable gets high CPU and disk usage, and takes a few minutes to finish. During this period, the machine is kind  of locked out for any other tasks to perform.

How can stop the antimalware service from being triggered in this case?
I checked the internet, but in my version of windows 10, I cannot find the place that I can add the exclusions to the windows defender.

Comment: install a different AV suite, the defender [runs every unknown software in an emulator](https://i.blackhat.com/us-18/Thu-August-9/us-18-Bulazel-Windows-Offender-Reverse-Engineering-Windows-Defenders-Antivirus-Emulator.pdf) (page 20). on dev devices were files change very often this causes perf issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can add your workspace folder(s) to the exclusion list under:
   `Settings -> Update & Security -> Windows Security -> Virus & threat protection -> Manage settings` (under "Virus & threat protection settings" heading).
2. Scroll down to `Exclusions -> Add or remove exclusions`. 
   ([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security))

You could even add eclipse itself as an exclusion, but I personally don't recommend that for security reasons.